# What are practical examples of using composite types in numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, types

The numpy [documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.dtype.html#numpy-dtype) describes the option to create custom composite types.

#### How should one use them?

I can imagine a practical example being a composite time format that would could be used to unify python, hdf5 and numpy as for example:

```
custom_time = np.dtype( [ ('h', np.int8) , ('m', np.int8), ('s', np.float)] )

t = custom_time(23,59,59.99999)
```

*(the line above doesn't work - I get `TypeError: 'numpy.dtype[void]' object is not callable`)*

#### Perhaps you have used composite types and have an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Custom types are meant to be used in Numpy arrays and not as stand-alone types. Here is an example:

```py
# Declare the type
custom_time = np.dtype( [ ('h', np.int8) , ('m', np.int8), ('s', np.float64)] )

# Create an array with 2 items of custom_time
arr = np.array([(4, 8, 15.16), (23, 42, 0.815)], dtype=custom_time)

# Access the fields
print(arr['h'])   # [4 23]
print(arr['s'])   # [15.16 0.815]
```

Comment: Are there any other benefit to using the composite type instead of having three arrays?

Comment: It is mainly for convenience. For example, you can sort this array easily while sorting 3 arrays with a given key ordering is much more tricky. It could also be important for performance since the *memory layout* is not the same. That being said, using many array is generally significantly faster unless the Number of array is big (eg. > 20). The reason is that basic array operations can make use of SIMD instructions while AFAIK composite types cannot (yet).